# How to use a Timer without a delay?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, delay, countdowntimer

I know that:

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

means delay for exactly one second before executing the code, but it there a way to use a timer to just count the time that past when the program executes without delaying the program? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).

Comment: You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after the event you want to time and subtract one from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the current time in a variable

```
long oldTime = System.nanoTime();
```

At the end of your program, print the current time - the old time and that will be the execution time in nano seconds.

```
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - oldTime));
```

Comment: Also, `System..currentTimeMillis()` is limited to the precision of the system clock, usually around `15ms`. `nanoTime` is always a better choice for timing events. Although, obviously any benchmark using this naive approach will be deeply flawed in any case.

Comment: Well, keyboard input at best is 30 ms, right? so shouldn't 15ms be more than enough?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard good answer anyway.